# Merge Method not working

Tags: java, jpa

The following code didn't update the database.
But the new value is in the object.

```
<h:outputText value="Nachname:" />
    <p:inplace editor="true">
       <p:ajax event="save" listener="#{managedBean.updateKunde()}" update="panelAendern" />
      <p:inputText value="#{managedBean.auswahl.nachname}"></p:inputText>
    </p:inplace>
```

And here is my ManagedBean Method:

```
@EJB
private KundenBeanLocal kunde;

public void updateKunde() {
    kunde.kundenUpdate(auswahl);
}
```

And my SessionBean:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

@Override
public void kundenUpdate(Kunde kunde) {
    em.merge(kunde);
    em.flush();

}
```

As i said, the new value is standing in the Kunden object. Only the update in the database is not working.

Comment: if the right value is in the object, PrimeFaces/JSF did its job and this is only jpa related (did you check if a commit is done)

Comment: Where is your transaction demarcated, where does it get committed?

Comment: -Chris: I use JTA

Comment: -Kukeltje: Yes i have checked. And yes, i does a commit

Answer (score 0):

Ok, have found and solved my problem. 
I have set at the OneToMany and OneToOne relationship the

> cascade=CascadeType.ALL

THX at all